# ReCaptcha Enterprise in Angular component shows console error when loading or resetting

Tags: angular, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I have a Login page in Angular who shows a reCaptcha challenge to be completed only when the userName has been attepting to logIn with an invalid password several times in a short time lapse.

When the component that contains the reCaptcha widget is shown, everything works fine and the backend validation works correctly. The problem comes up when the user completes the challenge and after 2 minutes, the token expires which rises an event (who also works fine).

The problem is that when the token expires or when I call the reset function (happens with certain navigations, our login page is by steps), it logs some errors in my chrome debug console who talk about an ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE, it makes a network call that rises this error.

I'm thinking that maybe it is a headers problem but i'm not sure.

I leave here a copy and paste from my chrome debug console window.

11:34:24.633 GET https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep 304

11:34:24.633 [www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png:1](http://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/logo_48.png:1) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep

11:34:24.782 anchor:184 GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/webworker.js?hl=es&v=qljbK_DTcvY1PzbR7IG69z1r net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE 200

11:34:24.782 [www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/webworker.js?hl=es&v=qljbK_DTcvY1PzbR7IG69z1r:1](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/webworker.js?hl=es&v=qljbK_DTcvY1PzbR7IG69z1r:1) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Any help or comment would be appreciated. Have a nice day and thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a Stackblitz? It's difficult to know how to help without seeing the implementation and HTTP requests being made.